PowerBI Compare two colums with result true/false
I am new to power bi and I want a result of true or false if the 4PS column is larger than the AFAS column. I have made a measurement for this, but it gives the error message that it cannot find the leave registration table. This name is really correct (it is an Excel import) but I don't think that should matter. Is the formula good or should I think of something completely different?
vergelijking uren = IF('factSiteManagementHours'[Hours_SMH] >= 'verlofregistratie'[aantal uur(getal)], "True", "False")
enter image description here

Since you are retrieving values from 2 different tables, you will need to retrieve the individual row's value and set it to a variable before comparing them.
Measure:
VAR Hours_SMH = MAXX(factSiteManagementHours, 'factSiteManagementHours'[Hours_SMH]) //Gets value from table

VAR aantal_uur = MAXX(verlofregistratie, 'verlofregistratie'[aantal uur(getal)) //Gets value from table

RETURN Hours_SMH >= aantal_uur


you can try this
vergelijking uren =
IF (
    MAX ( 'factSiteManagementHours'[Hours_SMH] )
        >= MAX ( 'verlofregistratie'[aantal uur(getal)] ),
    "True",
    "False"
)

